# Hardrives not automounting using fstab when using "reboot command"

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

Hey I've been trying to auto mount 2 of external hard drives at startup.

But only one of the hardrives partition mounts fine on start up but the other one does not. They mount successfully when I use the

```
sudo mount -a
```

command.

Here is my blkid

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="8B12-9112" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: UUID="29b6c2f5-5469-49f2-abd5-daa9149021cc" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Rubicon" UUID="A4A68E26A68DF8D6" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="0c4aec4f-914f-4b39-9e35-1ed7f51d5965" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Igloo" UUID="4C20B06C20B05F20" TYPE="ntfs"
```

and here is my fstab

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use $
UUID="4C20B06C20B05F20" /media/Igloo ntfs-3g defaults,sync 0 0
UUID="A4A68E26A68DF8D6" /media/Rubicon ntfs-3g defaults,sync 0 0
```

I've noticed that they both mount properly when I unplug the power and hard restart the Pi, but only one mounts when I use the "reboot" command. I'm new to linux, can anyone else?

Comment: Even when I add "mount -a" to the rc.local file it does not start up with both drives mounted.